# Both statement do the same thing

Tags: c++, pointers

I am sorry to ask you this but i am a newbie and came across this pointer issue. Can you please explain to me why do both statements end up doing the same thing?

```
int i=7;
```

*** first way

```
int *ptrInt;
ptrInt=&i;
```

************** second way

```
int *p_anotherWay=i;
```

Comment: Read about *assignment* and *initializer*.

Comment: The second won't compile. Did you mean `&i`? In which case it should be clear why initialising with `&i` has the same effect as assigning with `&i`.

Comment: I got confused when I did it the second way and I did not want to compile and see what the compiler says but get an understanding as to what is happening at the low level. I see that the first way is the right way whether it be a one step or a two step process. The second step is wrong but not really wrong till the compiler says you  cannot do it. It is essentially taking a garbage value in memory who value is 7 in this case and setting to p_anotherway. Correct me if I am wrong. I did compile and it did bark at me.

Comment: @user3897363: It's wrong because the types don't match; you can't initialise `int*` from `int`, because the language doesn't allow that type conversion without a cast. And if the compiler says it's wrong, then it's wrong (unless the compiler is wrong, but in this case it's right).

Answer (score 4):

They don't.

The first statement assigns the value of the memory address of `i` to `ptrInt`.
The second statement assigns the value of `i` itself to `ptrInt`, not its address.

Also, the second statement isn't totally well-formed. It compiles on some compilers, and doesn't compile on others. (These 'others' are actually doing it right)

Comment: So the right way would be to say int *ptr=&intVariable; ?

Comment: Thank you. I got my doubts clarified. address-of & and * dereferencing. I got confused in the second statement cause the address is also an integer and being assigned as an address of value 7. Which in essence  could be anything.

Comment: It should be mentioned, that the 2nd example [even doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/OtGDEC).

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 7;
int *pI = &i; // pointer to i
int *pSomewhere = (int*)i; // pointer to address 0x7
```

Comment: -1 `int *pSomewhere = i;` [won't compile at all](http://ideone.com/OtGDEC) because of mismatching types.

Comment: Yes I got it. Thank you guys. I am okay with the fundamentals after this exercise. The & is the address of and get the address of the variable on the stack. The * is the value stored at location pointed to by the pointer. I realize that when you use a pointer like a normal variable, you get the memory location stored in the pointer.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Brute force casting doesn't really help out with the primary problem/misconception. The error was issued right away, and properly conceived on the semantical level by the OP. Don't hurt this understanding now, by just proposing brute force casting! (I would even downvote again, if I could)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I'm not proposing anything, I'm putting up an example (of in this case valid code) and commenting on exactly what the OP's problem was. But thanks for the down vote :(

Comment: @BeyelerStudios _"I'm not proposing anything"_ Of course you do! It's at least the ***only point*** of your _"answer"_ to propose some code to _"fix the problem"_. No more explanations than the (very narrow) comments. Just using this format deserves a down vote for a VLQ answer, so what you're bothering about actually?!?